# My network stack is suddenly not connecting to my gateway

Tags: networking

I have a box called testbox that I use when I'm doing major new development as my, well, testbox. :) It's IP is 10.0.0.51 and it sits next to my primary unix workstation which is 10.0.0.101. These both plug wired into the same switch.

My testbox has been off for several months and I just powered it back on to start a new major project. I tried running and upgrade and it didn't seem to be connecting to the WAN. I pinged the switch and got no response. I pinged my Ubuntu workstation and that worked fine.

I try to run traceroute and it's not installed, and, of course, I can't install it because I can't reach the WAN. I find out that MTR replaces it, but when I run it on both boxes, I get no data and I can't figure out how to use it. I get:

[image]

Can't figure out what to do next.

Here's some output from ip command:

```
thomas@testbox:~$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.51  metric 100 
thomas@testbox:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:60:00:12:a7:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.51/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1778:a166:b6e:94ae/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: @JeffSchaller The link light on the server is lit. Remember that it can connect to other devices on the same switch, it just can't get to the gateway.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for your help. Added ip command output.

Comment: Just checking... 1. You've confirmed that ping across the LAN works to and from your test box. 2. You can or cannot ping the router? 3. Are you considering switch and router to be equivalent (you talked about "pinging the switch") or is it a managed switch? 4. What is the LAN-side IP address of your router? (According to `ip route` your test box reckons is should be `10.0.0.1/24`.)

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the help. You pointed me to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently, I had changed my network topology since the last time I used this computer. By running ip route on both the working computer and the broken, I discovered they were pointing to different gateways.

It seems that all of the information about changing network configuration on Ubuntu at the command line is out of date, so I finally just plugged back into my server and changed the default gateway and DNS to 10.0.0.5 by hand. As soon as I did, everything started working.

Comment: Good to hear it's fixed. What information are you reading that's out of date? Aren't you using DHCP on your network?

Comment: @roaima No, not DHCP, because this is a server and I need to know it's IP address. I'm doing DHCP on my workstation which is why the settings were correct.

Comment: @roaima I couldn't find any accurate description of where the gateway and IP address is stored. Still don't know where it is, so I logged in and used the GUI.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the reminder, but you can't accept your own answer for 48 hours. Please feel free to upvote, though. :)